# Google Analytics measurement protocol session control not working

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm trying to use manual session control with the Google Analyitics measurement API, and I cannot get it to work. After a bunch of fiddling, as a basic test case I set up a simple test site in analytics, and manually made the following requests to it:

```
?v=1&t=event&tid= (myid) &cid= (uid1) &ec=SessionTest&ea=TestStart&sc=start
?v=1&t=event&tid= (myid) &cid= (uid1) &ec=SessionTest&ea=TestEnd&sc=end
?v=1&t=event&tid= (myid) &cid= (uid2) &ec=SessionTest&ea=TestStart&sc=start
?v=1&t=event&tid= (myid) &cid= (uid2) &ec=SessionTest&ea=TestEnd&sc=end
```

Then looking at the analytics and waiting, the sessions in question still just time out after the normal 30 mins, instead of ending with the "sc=end" request. For example, under the "real-time -> events" page about 5 minutes after making the requests I still both of the "users" under the "Active Users" tab, and the page still claims there are "Right now: 2 active users on the site".

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.  Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: Same here... any idea?

Comment: @mllm Hi, did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: @z1ad I'm afraid not :(